# Codeception 2.1 dev branch installation phpunit requirements

Tags: symfony, phpunit, codeception

I'm trying to install the codeception dev branch of 2.1.x for my Symfony project. Using composer, its unable to match the requirements:

```
[01:36 PM]-[root@oracle]-[~]
# phpunit --version
PHPUnit 4.8.11 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

[02:03 PM]-[vagrant@oracle]-[/var/www]-[svn]
$ composer require --dev "codeception/codeception:2.1.3"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for codeception/codeception 2.1.3 -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[2.1.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.11
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.10
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.9
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.8
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.7
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.6
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.4
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.3
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.2
    - Can only install one of: phpunit/phpunit[4.8.0, 4.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: phpunit/phpunit[4.8.0, 4.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: phpunit/phpunit[4.8.0, 4.6.6].
    - codeception/codeception 2.1.3 requires phpunit/phpunit ~4.8.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.0, 4.8.1, 4.8.10, 4.8.11, 4.8.2, 4.8.3, 4.8.4, 4.8.5, 4.8.6, 4.8.7, 4.8.8, 4.8.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.1
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit == 4.6.6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.6.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Strangely after this, phpunit somehow downgrades to version 4.6.6

```
$ phpunit --version

==== Redirecting to composer installed version in vendor/phpunit ====

PHPUnit 4.6.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

Note I'm currently using CentOS 6.5 in a vagrant environment.

**EDIT:** composer.json

```
require: {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.6.*",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "~2.0",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.0.*",
        "jquery/jquery":  "1.10.*",
        "components/jqueryui": "1.11.*",
        "components/modernizr": "*",
        "knplabs/knp-menu":             "~2.0@alpha",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":      "~2.0@alpha",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "kuleuven/shibboleth-bundle": "dev-master",
        "liip/functional-test-bundle": "~1.0",
        "leaseweb/api-caller-bundle": "*",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.0",
        "FortAwesome/Font-Awesome": "*",
        "brown298/data-tables-bundle": "0.4.*",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "mmoreram/controller-extra-bundle": "1.0.*@dev"
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste your `composer.json` require section as well? My guess is that you have a requirement on the 4.6 version of `phpunit/phpunit` in there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the composer.json to the OP. I tried with v4.6.6 of phpunit/phpunit as well. What else am I missing?